# TSQL - Use a Derived Select Column in the Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, case

Is there a way in TSQL to do something like this:

```
select a,b,c,
case 
  when a=1 then 5
  when a=2 then 6
end as d
from some_table
where d=6
```

The actual case statement is really complex, so I'm trying to avoid repeating it in the where clause?  Are there any tricks to do this?

(I think there's a trick in MySQL to use "having d=6").

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
select
    a, b, c
from (
    select
        a, b, c,
        case 
          when a=1 then 5
          when a=2 then 6
        end as d
    from some_table
) as t
where d=6
```

Answer (score 8):

This is a good place to use [CTEs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx), e.g.:

```
WITH MassagedData (a, b, c, d) AS
(
    select a, b, c,
        case 
          when a=1 then 5
          when a=2 then 6
        end as d
    from some_table
)

SELECT a,b,c
FROM MassagedData
where d=6
```

Comment: Wish this was upvoted more as it's much less noisy than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to implement your `case` statement as a function. Especially good for conversion or calculation issues.  What's nice about functions is that the 'business' logic is in one place and can easily be reused in other queries.

```
-- sample code not tested

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_MyConvertA(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @a int
)
RETURNS int -- for example
AS
BEGIN
-- Declare the return variable here
DECLARE @ResultVar as int

-- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
set @ResultVar = case when @a = 1 then 5 when @a = 2 then 6 else 10 end

-- Return the result of the function
RETURN @ResultVar

END
GO

-- now you case write your query
select a,b,c,  dbo.fn_MyConvertA(a) as d
from some_table          
where dbo.fn_MyConvertA(a)=6
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your posted query a sub-query and select from it where d = 6.  As far as I know there is no way to reference a derived column in the same query.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to agree with [AlexKuznetsov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096695/tsql-use-a-derived-select-column-in-the-where-clause/2096703#2096703) on this one, but I would also add that if your query is (no matter how much more complex) limiting in the `WHERE` clause cases that exist in the `CASE`, then those `CASE`s will never be returned and shouldn't be selected in the first place.

For example, you're setting `d` to '6' where `a` is '2', then limiting to `WHERE d = 6`, so you could instead do:

```
SELECT a,b,c,
    6 AS d
FROM some_table
WHERE a = 2
```

This will return the same results in a more optimized and clean fashion. This is why, IMHO, there's no point in being able to reference a derived column.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method to  this is to use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
select a,b,c,
from some_table
CROSS APPLY (SELECT case 
                    when a=1 then 5
                    when a=2 then 6
                    end) CxA(d)
where d=6
```